# Flat to Hierarchical XSLT Transform

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, hierarchical, flat

I'm having pretty significant trouble figuring out how to convert a flat XML into a hierarchical result using an XSLT V1 transform.  I would post my XSLT, but I'm not sure I'm even approaching it correctly.  I know I need to create and use Keys, but, regardless of attempting to apply every example I've found here and elsewhere (many, many, many...), it simply doesn't work.

Here is the input:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header/>
    <env:Body>
        <tns:getClientRS xmlns:tns="http://services.xxx.com/ClientService">
            <tns:Acknowledgement>Process completed successfully.</tns:Acknowledgement>
            <tns:client>
                <tns:ClientID>515164</tns:ClientID>
                <tns:episodeID>1</tns:episodeID>
                <tns:guarantorID>1</tns:guarantorID>
            </tns:client>
            <tns:client>
                <tns:ClientID>515164</tns:ClientID>
                <tns:episodeID>1</tns:episodeID>
                <tns:guarantorID>2</tns:guarantorID>
            </tns:client>
            <tns:plan>
                <tns:ClientID>515164</tns:ClientID>
                <tns:episodeID>1</tns:episodeID>
                <tns:guarantorID>1</tns:guarantorID>
                <tns:guarantorPlan>1</tns:guarantorPlan>
            </tns:plan>
            <tns:plan>
                <tns:ClientID>515164</tns:ClientID>
                <tns:episodeID>1</tns:episodeID>
                <tns:guarantorID>2</tns:guarantorID>
                <tns:guarantorPlan>2</tns:guarantorPlan>
            </tns:plan>
        </tns:getClientRS>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

and desired response XML:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header/>
    <env:Body>
        <tns:getClientRS xmlns:tns="http://services.xxx.com/ClientService">
            <tns:Acknowledgement>Process completed successfully.</tns:Acknowledgement>
            <tns:clients>
                <tns:ClientID>515164</tns:ClientID>
                <tns:episodes>
                    <tns:Episode>
                        <tns:episodeID>1</tns:episodeID>
                        <tns:Guarantors>
                            <tns:Guarantor>
                                <tns:guarantorID>1</tns:guarantorID>
                                <tns:Plan>
                                    <tns:guarantorPlan>1</tns:guarantorPlan>
                                </tns:Plan>
                            </tns:Guarantor>
                            <tns:Guarantor>
                                <tns:guarantorID>2</tns:guarantorID>
                                <tns:Plan>
                                    <tns:guarantorPlan>2</tns:guarantorPlan>
                                </tns:Plan>
                            </tns:Guarantor>
                        </tns:Guarantors>
                    </tns:Episode>
                </tns:episodes>
            </tns:clients>
        </tns:getClientRS>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Just trying to keep things simple, but there could be multiple clients and multiple episodes.  I suspect that if I can figure out the guarantors, I can figure out the episodes and clients.

I really need help here.  No matter what I do, I get *only* the first of each key... that is, guarantor 1 and plan 1.  That's it.

Comment: "*I need it to be namespace prefix neutral.*" What exactly does that mean? -- You should also explain in few words the logic behind the transformation. For example: will there always be only one client? -- And which version of XSLT?

Comment: Check edits.  I don't really care so much about namespace prefix...

Comment: "And which version of XSLT?" - if you give that last piece of info we should be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry.  It is a V1 Transform.

Comment: Which processor specifically/ You could save quite a lot of work if your processor supports some EXSLT extension functions.

Comment: IBM DataPower.  It does support a subset of EXSLT.  You might have to be more specific on what you need to use for me to know if DP supports it.

Comment: The set:distinct() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT set:distinct()**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:tns="http://services.xxx.com/ClientService"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
extension-element-prefixes="set">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="client" match="tns:client" use="tns:ClientID" />
<xsl:key name="plan" match="tns:plan" use="concat(tns:ClientID, '|', tns:episodeID)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <env:Envelope xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <env:Header/>
        <env:Body>
            <tns:getClientRS>
                <xsl:copy-of select="tns:Acknowledgement"/>
                <tns:clients>
                    <!-- client -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(env:Envelope/env:Body/tns:getClientRS/tns:client/tns:ClientID)">
                        <xsl:variable name="clientID" select="." />
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                         <tns:episodes>
                            <!-- episode -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(key('client', .)/tns:episodeID)">
                                <tns:Episode>
                                    <xsl:variable name="episodeID" select="." />
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                                        <!-- plans -->
                                        <tns:Guarantors>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="key('plan', concat($clientID, '|', $episodeID))">
                                                <tns:Guarantor>
                                                    <xsl:copy-of select="tns:guarantorID"/>
                                                    <tns:Plan>
                                                        <xsl:copy-of select="tns:guarantorPlan"/>
                                                    </tns:Plan>
                                                </tns:Guarantor>
                                            </xsl:for-each> 
                                        </tns:Guarantors>
                                </tns:Episode>
                            </xsl:for-each> 
                        </tns:episodes> 
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </tns:clients>
            </tns:getClientRS>
        </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This returns the expected result for your input example - though it could be partly a matter of coincidence. If you have multiple plans per guarantor, you'll need to add one more level.

Comment: Nice!  I wanted to avoid the brute force approach, but honestly, even with that, I would not anytime in the near future have come up with this.  I think I can modify for my need.  I'm going to keep the post unanswered for now in the event I have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to write a whole XSLT file, but have you tried the following approach?

```
<xsl:foreach select="tns:client">
  <xsl:if test="
    not( preceding-sibling::tns:getClientRS[ 
      not(./tns:ClientID = current()/tns:ClientID ) 
    ] )
  ">
  <xsl:variable name="ClientID" select="tns:ClientID"/>
```

Then loop through the clients and plans as needed (i.e. `select="ancestor::tns:getClientRS/tns:plan[tns:ClientId = $ClientID]"`).

Comment: This is not a good approach - read here why :http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Thanks. I agree it will become slow when the number of elements in the list is great: the Muenchian method is certainly better where the document is large. For smaller documents where parsing the XML and XSLT is the larger task and execution time is comparatively fast, the difference is negligible.

Comment: We don't know how large the document is (or can be).